# Check if an extension is in use before dropping it in a postgres db

Tags: postgresql

I want to drop unnecessary extensions in my database. But before i do that , i want to make sure that they are not being used anywhere in the database. I have tried using the below query to find functions that make use of the extension like pgcrypto  . Im not sure if this is enough

```
select proname,prosrc from pg_proc where prosrc ilike '% encrypt%'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no good way to do that.

Your example shows that it is difficult to check if extensions are used in database functions, but you will never be able to tell if SQL statements sent from the client use the extension just by querying the database.